# Choosing boundary conditions for $(\frac{-d^2}{dx^2})^m$ on $H^m((0,1))$?

Tags: differential-operators, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the differential operator $D:$
$$
Du:=\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}u
$$
on the function space $$C=\{ u\in C^2([0,1]):u(0)=u(1)=0\}.$$

It's not hard to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors(eigenfunctions) for $D$ by soloving the eigenvalue problem:
$$
-u''=\lambda u\qquad u(0)=u(1)=0.
$$

Here are my **questions**:

> - For each of the differential operators $D^m(m=2,3,4,\dots)$, what boundary conditions should one choose to ensure that $D^m$ and $D$ share the *same* eigenfunctions? I have no idea for even $m=2$.
> - What if 
>     $$
>   Du:=\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}u+u?
>   $$

Comment: This has been put on `math.SE` for several days without an answer. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy. If the boundary condition for D is, say, $Lu=0$, then for $D^m$ you should pose the boundary conditions
$$Lu=LDu=LD^2u=...=LD^{m-1}u=0.$$

Comment: Then the corresponding function space for $D^m$ is `$\{u\in C^m((0,1)):Lu=LDu=\cdots =LD^{m-1}=0\}$`, isn't it? I'm afraid I'm not able to follow your "hint" to give a proof that $D^m$ and $D$ have same eigenfunctions. It seems that the results are the same for any linear differential operator $D$, right?


Comment: Suppose $Du=\lambda u$ and $u$ satisfies the boundary condition
$Lu=0$. Then $D^2u=\lambda Du=\lambda^2u$ and $Lu=LDu=\lambda Lu=0$.
Now iterate this argument.

Comment: Fair enough. Another problem is that whether the "reverse" is also true: Denote the boundary condition (in your answer) for $D^m$ as $\tilde{L}u=0$ and $D^mu=\lambda^m u$; can one have $Du=\lambda u$? 